# What's the maximum delay for a deferred transaction

Tags: deferred-transactions

I know that deferred transactions can just be dropped by the nodes if they are too far in the future, but I wonder what the maximum delay for a deferred transaction is in practice on the mainnet.

I saw someone mentioning a `max-deferred-transaction-time` in the node's `config.ini`, but the default config does not mention this parameter.
Is there a default value? What configuration do most nodes have on the mainnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [EOS-Mainnet's genesis.json file](https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-MainNet/blob/master/genesis.json):

```
{
  "initial_timestamp": "2018-06-08T08:08:08.888",
  "initial_key": "EOS7EarnUhcyYqmdnPon8rm7mBCTnBoot6o7fE2WzjvEX2TdggbL3",
  "initial_configuration": {
    "max_block_net_usage": 1048576,
    "target_block_net_usage_pct": 1000,
    "max_transaction_net_usage": 524288,
    "base_per_transaction_net_usage": 12,
    "net_usage_leeway": 500,
    "context_free_discount_net_usage_num": 20,
    "context_free_discount_net_usage_den": 100,
    "max_block_cpu_usage": 200000,
    "target_block_cpu_usage_pct": 1000,
    "max_transaction_cpu_usage": 150000,
    "min_transaction_cpu_usage": 100,
    "max_transaction_lifetime": 3600,
    "deferred_trx_expiration_window": 600, // LOOK HERE
    "max_transaction_delay": 3888000,
    "max_inline_action_size": 4096,
    "max_inline_action_depth": 4,
    "max_authority_depth": 6
  }
}
```

But as far as I know there are no guarantees about deferred transactions either way.

Comment: So, can't we use `sleep` in the cpp code to execute a particular action after given time? Just a thought.

Comment: if a transaction takes more than 200ms it won't be included in the blockchain though, so sleep won't work if it delays the transaction too much

Comment: I am finding difficulty in cancelling the deferred transaction. Can you please point me in a right direction? I am going through eos source code where I found the `apply_context.cpp` file in which the function is defined but I am unable to use that function in my contract.

Comment: there's a `cancel_deferred()` function in eosio but i'd suggest you ask a new question if you run into any problems, as this is not related to OP's question and it's bad practice to talk off-topic in comments

Comment: What's the difference between `deferred_trx_expiration_window` and `max_transaction_delay`?

Comment: Found it. deferred_trx_expiration_window;      ///< the number of seconds after the time a deferred transaction can first execute until it expires
   uint32_t   max_transaction_delay;               ///< the maximum number of seconds that can be imposed as a delay requirement by authorization checks. So this answer seems wrong, it should be `max_transaction_delay` which is 45 days